# How to know stream order in QGIS on output of r.stream.extract

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, stream-order, qgis-grass-plugin

I have stream order created over DEM using r.stream.extract , which gives 3 output files:

1. stream_raster - raster map stores extracted streams.
2. stream_vector - extracted points for each stream segment
3. flow accumulation

Can I know which segment comes after each segment in QGIS.
Are these stored with any IDs somewhere so that I can know flow direction or next point from stream_vector for next flow segment

Answer (score 1):

The GRASS GIS Addon [v.stream.order](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/v.stream.order.html) computes the stream order of stream networks stored in a vector map at specific outlet vector points. It offers Strahler's stream order, Shreve's stream magnitude, Scheidegger's stream magnitude, and Drwal's stream hierarchy.
Likewise, there is the [r.stream.order](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.stream.order.html) addon.